# Why Voltage is divided in a series circuit? What is the need of it to be divided?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

When a Circuit is connected in series with 2 resistors(10 ohms each) and a 9v battery and a bulb, why does the Voltage gets divided btw resistors?What is the need for it to divide? Pls don’t tell any water example, i literally don't understand.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have a large resistor, say $10\,\mathrm{\Omega}$, on a wire, then an "electric pressure" from e.g. a battery pushes the electric charges (the current) through this resistance. The "electric pressure" is thus high on one side of the resistor but doesn't have to be high on the other side.*

Voltage is a term for this "electric pressure" difference.**

- Now, what if you break your large $10\,\mathrm{\Omega}$ resistor in two $5\,\mathrm{\Omega}$ resistors instead? The "electric pressure" will still be the same on either side of this resistance bulk, since the total resistance still is the same. But what is the pressure in-between them?

Well, it only takes half as much "electric pressure" difference - so only half the voltage - to squeeze charges through the first resistor. The "electric pressure" is thus halved in-between them. It takes the other half of the voltage to squeeze them through the final resistor.

From the outside it looks as though each resistor divides the voltage. We thus often refer to the in-between voltage value as if a *voltage drop* took place. But all that happens is that only the necessary amount of voltage is established across each resistor, and overall you then add it up.

---

<sup>* *If the "pressure" was high on both sides of a resistance, then the charges would have no incentive to move. Particles of any kind always tend to move towards lower "pressure" because that means moving towards a point of less "repulsion", which in electric contexts means less electric potential energy. In the water analogy that you dislike, we are dealing with actual water pressure which is why this analogy is often used.*</sup>

<sup>** *When I say "electric pressure" then I am referring to ***electrical potential energy per unit of charge***, also often just called ***electric potential***. Voltage is a term for the difference in electric potential energy per unit charge between two points.*</sup>

Comment: Hey Steven! This is a Long-time Doubt i had.  Thank you so much for explaining so that i could understand finally and thank you for respecting what i asked(water analogy)

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer (with many simplifying assumptions):

[Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction) says that if I add up the electric field at points all around a circuit (of the kind you describe), the sum will be zero.

You can add up the electric field at points all around a circuit by mentally chopping the circuit into lumps (e.g. resistor, battery, bulb), adding up the electric fields across each lump separately, and then adding the results.

The sum of the electric fields across a lump is also known as the *voltage*.  By Faraday's law, **the sum of the voltages across all the lumps must be zero**.

Depending on how it is interpreted, that answers your question.  However, we can say a bit more...

The battery voltage is fixed (9 volts), so the sum of the voltages across the other lumps must be -9 volts.  Those other lumps are the two resistors and the bulb (we treat the bulb as just another resistor) so the 9 volts must be divided up between the resistors.

## A longer answer:

Faraday's law, which is one of Maxwell's four fundamental equations of electromagnetism, states that the integral of the electric field around a circuit must be equal to the change in magnetic flux through the circuit.

$\oint{\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{\Phi_B}}{\mathrm{d}t}$

This result was arrived at by experimental observation but is essentially consistent with later theory (e.g. quantum electrodynamics).

In a circuit with a battery, resistors, and a bulb, in which the current has been running more than a few seconds, there is negligible change in magnetic flux and so the integral of the electric field around the circuit roughly zero:

$\oint{\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell} \approx 0$

The integral of the electric field between two points $a$ and $b$ is $V_{a,b}=-\int^b_a\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell$ (there are other expressions but this is common and arises from the work required to move an electric charge in the field). You know this better as the *voltage* between points $a$ and $b$.

We chop up the circuit into lumps -- a resistor from point $a$ to point $b$, another resistor from $c$ to $d$, a bulb from $e$ to $f$, a battery from $g$ to $h$, wires.

We measure the voltage across each lump -- $V_{a,b}$, $V_{c,d}$, and so on -- and add the voltages up:

$V_{a,b}+V_{c,d}+V{e,f}+V{g,h} = \int^a_b\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell +
 \int^c_d\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell+ \int^e_f\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell+ \int^g_h\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell$.

But the sum of all the electric field integrals for each lump are equal to the
electric field integral around the whole loop

$\int^a_b\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell +
 \int^c_d\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell+ \int^e_f\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell+ \int^g_h\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell =  \oint\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\ell =0$

because the loop is made up of the lumps

We assume the battery voltage is fixed at 9 volts.  (In truth it is slowly declining but over the time that we are measuring it's not going to be noticeable).  So the voltages across the other components have to add up to -9 volts.

We also assume that the voltage in the wires is zero.  This is not completely accurate but the voltage drop across a copper wire in a circuit like the one in your example will be fairly tiny.

All we have left now are the resistors and the bulb.  The bulb acts more or less like a resistor too, once the circuit has been running for a while.  (While it is heating up it isn't quite like a normal resistor but once it has reached a steady temperature it is).  So the 9 volts must be divided up between the resistors.

Making this quantitative using your example...

The voltage across a resistor is proportional to the current in the resistor.  This is *Ohm's law*, $V=IR$, another law that was the result of experimental observation.  The constant of proportionality, $R$, is called the *resistance*.

You have three resistors in your circuit, $R_1 = 10 \Omega$, $R_2 = 10 \Omega$, and the unknown $R_3$ (the bulb's resistance).  The current $I$ flows through all of these resistors, because electrons don't escape from the circuit.  We assume that charge isn't building up in any particular part of the circuit (this is a pretty good assumption once the circuit has been running for a bit), so $I$ is the same in all the resistors.

So, using ohms law for the battery and each of the resistors you have:

9 volts $- IR_1 - IR_2 - IR_3 = 0$.

You can factor out the current:

$9V - I(R_1 + R_2 + R_3) = 0$

and rearrange:

$I=\frac{9V}{R_1 + R_2 + R_3}$.

Again applying Ohm's law the voltage across resistor 1 is:

$-V_1=-IR_1=-\frac{9V}{R_1+R_2+R_3}R_1=-9V\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2+R_3}$.

And you get similar expressions for the voltages across resistors 2 and 3.

And if you add up $V_1$, $V_2$, and $V_3$ you get -9 volts, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, voltage is defined to be the potential *difference between two points*.

Now consider the two resistors in series.
[image]

Then it is easy to see, that the potential difference (i.e. the voltage)
between points $A$ and $C$ is the same
as the potential difference between $A$ and $B$
plus the potential difference between $B$ and $C$.
$$V_{A\to C}=V_{A\to B}+V_{B\to C}$$
Or in other words: The voltage between $A$ and $C$ is divided
into the voltage between $A$ and $B$ and the voltage between
$B$ and $C$.